Error "Package libsdl2-dev is not available" when installing "libsdl2-dev" in WSL2
I am trying to install package libsdl2-dev in wsl2 with command apt install libsdl2-dev. Then an error appears:
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3737]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Admin>ubuntu
root@DESKTOP-U2KMUFI:~# apt install libsdl2-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package libsdl2-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libsdl2-doc

E: Package 'libsdl2-dev' has no installation candidate
root@DESKTOP-U2KMUFI:~#

Could you elaborate on how to install libsdl2-dev properly?
